# How to output each symbol once from array?

Tags: for-loop, visual-c++, output

I'm trying to make program that outputs each symbol once. I don't know what to put in for loop.

I couldn't find way to output each symbol once from

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    char virkne[101];


    std::cin >> virkne;

    for (int i = 0; virkne[i] != '\0'; i++) {


        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Expected

entered: abbcccdddd
output: abcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt work.Output is the same what input.Example : Input = abbcccdddd, Output = abbcccdddd.

## include

int main() {

```
char virkne[101];


std::cin >> virkne;

for (int i = 0; virkne[i] != '\0'; i++) {

    char chr = virkne[i];
    std::cout << chr;

}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}